# Как отправить токены ethereum с помощью web3.js

Tags: node.js, bitcoin, криптовалюта

У меня все-таки получилось создать токены и перевести их все на свой адрес при создании.

Сейчас мне нужно переводить эти токены на другие адреса с помощью web3.js.
Есть ли простой способ сделать это? Что-нибудь похожее на отправку эфира?

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe',
    to: '0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe',
    value: '1000000000000000'
})
```

Нагуглил много страшных вещей:[вот](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/5039/how-to-use-web3-js-to-sign-a-contract-call) и [вот](https://tokenmarket.net/blog/creating-ethereum-smart-contract-transactions-in-client-side-javascript/)

Необходимо ли использовать все аргументы?

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы перевести токены - нужно вызвать соответствующий метод контракта токена, предварительно его подписав. Примерный код:

```
const sender = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKeyFrom);
const tokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
const data = tokenContract.methods["transfer"](toAddress, amount).encodeABI();
const tx = { 
  gas: '2000000',
  from: fromAddress,
  to: contractAddress,      
  data,
};
const signedTx = await sender.signTransaction(tx);
const result = await web3.eth
  .sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно отправить ERC-20 или BEP-20, [воспользуйтесь этим решением](https://github.com/react-declarative/erc20-payment-gateway). Передать токены можно используя промежуточный смарт-контракт, тогда история платежей будет в открытом доступе

```
contract PaymentGatewayContract {

    IERC20 private erc20;
    address public owner;

    uint256 public deployBlock;

    constructor(address _erc20Address) {
        erc20 = IERC20(_erc20Address);
        owner = msg.sender;
        deployBlock = block.number;
    }

    function sendUSDT(uint256 _amount, bytes32 _data) public {
        uint256 allowance = erc20.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));

        require(allowance >= _amount, "ERC20 allowance not sufficient");
        bool transferSuccess = erc20.transferFrom(msg.sender, owner, _amount);

        require(transferSuccess, "Failed to transfer ERC20");
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _amount, _data);
    }

    event Transfer(address indexed sender, uint256 amount, bytes32 _data);

}
```

Или, взаимодействуйте с смарт-контрактом токена напрямую через это ABI, оно универсальное для всех ERC-20 токенов. Вам потребуется вызвать методы `approve`  и `transferFrom`

```json
[
  {
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "name",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "_spender",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "name": "_value",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "name": "approve",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "type": "bool"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "totalSupply",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "_from",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "name": "_to",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "name": "_value",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "name": "transferFrom",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "type": "bool"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "decimals",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "type": "uint8"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "_owner",
        "type": "address"
      }
    ],
    "name": "balanceOf",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "balance",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "symbol",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "_to",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "name": "_value",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "name": "transfer",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "type": "bool"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "_owner",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "name": "_spender",
        "type": "address"
      }
    ],
    "name": "allowance",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "payable": true,
    "stateMutability": "payable",
    "type": "fallback"
  },
  {
    "anonymous": false,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "indexed": true,
        "name": "owner",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "indexed": true,
        "name": "spender",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "indexed": false,
        "name": "value",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Approval",
    "type": "event"
  },
  {
    "anonymous": false,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "indexed": true,
        "name": "from",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "indexed": true,
        "name": "to",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "indexed": false,
        "name": "value",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Transfer",
    "type": "event"
  }
]
```